# Streaming audio udp C

Tags: c

I'm writing a program with a client and a server I almost achieved it. 
At the moment I can execute the server on a port. The client in the same port with the IP adress and the name of the .wav file that I want to read.

Now what I'd like to do is making a timeout between each sendto() so that the client receives the packet and read them well. without that the client receives many packets at once and it losts many of them. 
So could someone tell me how it works  in UDP, and how to do that ?

Comment: It doesnt work in UDP.  UDP transmission is one-way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Comparison_of_UDP_and_TCP  You just send a stream of packets, if the client doesnt receive the packet, then it is lost and they will witness 'lag'

Comment: actually my question is not clear is just read it again.. what I'd like to do is making a timeout between each packet so that the client receive it in the right time.. because without that the client receive many at once and the sound is not very clear

Comment: You should rephrase your question then.  It is asking multiple things that are unrelated to your intended question.

Comment: What are you using to decode the audio?

Comment: padsp, and i use the functions write and read

Answer (score 1):

> making a timeout between each sendto()

I believe that you are asking how to put a small delay between each sendto().  If you open raw wav file and send bytes, there is a good chance that the data will be getting to the client much faster than it can play it.   If you want to stream data at the same rate as it is played, send data in chunks, then let the client request the next chunk.
If that is not an option, you can send a chunk of data (i.e. 20ms).  Then let the thread sleep for a little less than 20ms then send the next chunk.  Sleeps are kind of a hack.  Some sort of audio callback would be best on the server.  Bottom line is that your client buffer has to be big enough to consume the the amount of data your server is sending.

> without that the client receives many packets at once and it losts many of them

I believe that you are asking how to deal with the variety of packet inter arrival rates and the packet losses and out of order packets received.   It sounds like you were just sending packets at too fast a rate that your client could handle.  You might need a larger buffer on the client.

In any case, with UDP/IP, you have the following scenarios

- lost packets
- packets arriving out of order
- packets arriving in bursts: (each packet will not arrive exactly X ms apart)

To deal with this, you have to minimally have what is know as a dejitter buffer.   This is a buffer that collects packets as they arrive and inserts them typically in a ring buffer.  The buffer will have to be large enough to buffer up packets that your server is sending.  Your client is potentially consuming the packets from the buffer slower than the server is sending them (or vice versa).  In order to get packets in the right order and deal with losses, you have to detect it.  You can detect losses and out of order arrivals by simply numbering each packet that is sent.  As packets arrive you can put them into the buffer into the correct location.  If a packet is lost, you need to deal with that with some sort of loss concealment (playing silence, estimating the lost packet, etc.) which is beyond the scope of this question,

The RTP protocol is designed for streaming and is an application protocol that work over UDP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using UDP, which is connectionless, you don't really have a way to control the flow of packets unless you implement some kind of acknowledgement mechanism... at which point you might as well be using TCP because it already has that built in.

Although I don't have much experience in network programming, this looks a bit more complicated than it might seem at first glance. So UDP is connectionless. That speeds things up a lot, but there is a price to pay -- off the top of my head, packets can get lost *or* arrive out of order.

Those are situations you need to handle on the client end. Your client needs to be designed so that it accepts packets as they arrive at an arbitrary rate, skips over those that fail to arrive within a certain time (for live streaming, for buffered that doesn't matter) and takes order into consideration, which means that each packet needs to contain information about its place relative to previous packets.

Comment: Out of order packets are typically handled by having a timestamp on them. If it is older than one that has already played, it is discarded (in the case of linear media files being livestreamed).  To the OP, i would recommend watching some content on streaming sites and seeing how lag is handled and thinking about it.  twitch.tv is a good example